# What is the difference of double onion and just onion?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing

Can anyone eli5 the difference of [double onion](https://clearnetonion.eu.org/) and onion? How many hops will doubleonion use?

Answer (score 0):

This service looks like a proxy service, so no additional onion layers are applied. And - actually - it also looks like it's made for donation collecting only: free version is http/plaintext only, no SSL is employed. HTTPS is not just an encryption, but also a HTTP/2 enabler and filtering preventer. If the output node *is already* running a resource-consuming Tor instance, then let's encrypt certificate is nearly-nothing to run, and - speaking correctly - their nodes are nothing more than NGinx + tor on one node. I do not recommend you to use this - if you need it for free and secure - make an IPFS mirror of your website and put it into the clearnet via IPFS [just like this](https://www.geekdecoder.com/setting-up-ipfs-server-with-nginx-and-gateway/)